# SOAP UI: Can I add assertion to validate with local XML Schema file?

Tags: validation, soap, xsd, schema, soapui

I have created a Web Service (with Java, Axis). Depending on the content of the request, the response may have a different XSD. So, the WSDL only specifies that the response is of a generic XSD, and the responses comply to XSDs that import and extend the generic XSD.

Unfortunately, the Schema assertion fail because the XSD specified in the WSDL can only the generic one. Is there a way to manually specify which XSD I want the assertion to use? For instance, depending on the request I prepare, I know the specific XSD of the response. So, it would be perfect if I could say to SoapUI to assert the response by that XSD, which I can store either locally or at a url.

So, is there a way to make a schema assertion using a locally (or remotely) stored XML schema?

Thanks,

Markos

Comment: I have a similar problem, but it is not possible for me to export to jar as the current answer suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did after all is that I created a simple class to do this in Java.I exported the project as a jar, imported it in Groovy and just called it.

This is normal, as both Java and Groovy both play on the JVM, so it is perfectly normal to call classes and methods from one another.